# How to connect a FastAPI application and a PostgreSQL database on Digital Ocean

Tags: postgresql, fastapi, digital-ocean, asyncpg

For some context, the FastAPI app is running on Ubuntu in a digital ocean droplet, and the database is a digital ocean managed database in a cluster.

I recently restored the database from backup after a mishap, and was able to recover lost data after querying with psql. Since both of them bore "Primary Only" I thought there might be conflicts, so I went ahead to destroy the original database.

However, seeing that the FastAPI app cannot connect with the database on digital ocean, i ran `docker logs --tail 10 -f 2a7b5654b16b` and found out that indeed there's no connection, see error message snippet below.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 586, in _create_ssl_connection
    tr, pr = await loop.create_connection(
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1978, in create_connection
    ai_remote = f1.result()
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

On researching what the error message above means, I thought that it might need SSL certificate to encrypt connections between my client application and the database. I would have gone ahead to download and install the SSL certificate provided by Digital Ocean, but in database settings.py I saw that the environment variable for SSL is set to None; `DB_SSL: Final = None`, so I thought that means the application doesn't use database SSL after all.

The connection code looks like this;

```
    # DB settings
    # ------------------------
    DB_DRIVER: Final[str] = "postgresql+asyncpg"
    DB_HOST: Final[str] = os.environ.get("DB_HOST", "localhost")
    DB_PORT: Final[str] = os.environ.get("DB_PORT", "5432")
    DB_USER: Final[str] = os.environ.get("DB_USER", "postgres")
    DB_PASSWORD: Final[str] = os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD", "")
    DB_DATABASE: Final[str] = os.environ.get("DB_DATABASE", "postgres")
    # If set to True, will print the executed SQL queries
    DB_ECHO: Final[bool] = False
    DB_SSL: Final = None
    DB_USE_CONNECTION_FOR_REQUEST: Final[bool] = True
    DB_RETRY_LIMIT: Final[int] = 1
    DB_RETRY_INTERVAL: Final[int] = 1

    DB_DSN: Final[
        str
    ] = f"{DB_DRIVER}://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_DATABASE}"
```

```
db_engine = create_async_engine(
    Settings.DB_DSN,
    pool_size=10,
    max_overflow=10,
    echo=Settings.DB_ECHO,
    json_deserializer=orjson.loads,
    json_serializer=lambda j: orjson.dumps(j).decode("utf-8"),
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    pool_recycle=60,
    future=True,
)
```

I have never configured a database connection on digital ocean before so i don't know what to look out for, I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Have you verified that the actual `DB_HOST` / PORT etc. after resolving the environment variables points to the correct host/instance for your db host? Does that name resolve if you try to ping it from your droplet?

Comment: I am able to connect to the db with psql using the connection details from digital ocean. And i thought the app would pick up the connection details using `os.environ.get`. Have i answered your question, please.

Comment: No, you need to _verify that the connection details_ has been picked up from the environment (i.e. that they're set in the environment as you expect). If they haven't been set properly or they have the wrong value, you won't be able to connect - and you don't know whether your code is seeing the correct values. Start by outputting the values when you're connecting with `print` or a log statement, just to make sure you're actually trying to connect to the correct host in your code.

Comment: Thanks, i have seen the digital ocean doc on env vars, but it doesn't seem scalable considering i have a bunch of env vars in settings.py of my app. Will i have to manually add each env var? And what happened to the env vars that were set for the original database? Were they deleted when i destroyed that db?
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-linux

Comment: Environment variables are part of the environment you're running your application in. They're not part of the database. If you're using `.env` and settings.py and already have your database credentials there, you can use those values instead of referring to `os.environ`.

Comment: You are right, I've only added the 5 env vars that use `os.environ` using `nano ~/.bashrc`, but the issue persists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256244/discussion-between-uwem-uke-and-matslindh).